# Proper way to use morphia in a non-blocking I/O environment like Vert.x 3

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, vert.x

I'm currently tying to implement [morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia) (mongoDb's official Java ORM) with Vert.x 3 but it looks like all the queries and calls are done synchronously and can block the eventloop of Vert.x 3

How do turn this query into a non-blocking set of code.

```
DBObject query = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
        .add("albums",
                        new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch",
                                new BasicDBObject("$and", new BasicDBObject[] {
                                    new BasicDBObject("albumId", albumDto.getAlbumId()),
                                    new BasicDBObject("album",
                                        new BasicDBObject("$exists", false))
                })))
        .get();

Query<Artist> findQuery = datastore.createQuery(Artist.class, query);
Artist result = findQuery.get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use synchronous code in Vert.x you have 2 options:

- Use a worker verticle
- Wrap your call in a `executeBlocking` closure

A worker verticle is always executed with a thread from the worker pool. However if you want to mix both async and sync you probably want to use the second option. You can read all about `executeBlocking` [here](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#blocking_code). Given your example it would be something like:

```
DBObject query = ... // your definition is probably non blocking

vertx.executeBlocking(future -> {
  // Call blocking API that takes a significant amount of time to return
  Artist result = findQuery.get();
  future.complete(result);
}, res -> {
  System.out.println("The artist is: " + res.result());
});
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. I went with the executingBlocking.

Comment: If you want to be totally async then i'd recommend to look at the mongo-client which uses mongodb-async-driver but you loose the ORM features though :)

Comment: That sounds good, unfortunately the ORM is so important for me at the moment. The mongo-client required that I had to write a lot more code and JsonObject options.